# In Spark,while writing dataset into database it takes some pre-assumed time for save operation

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark

I ran the spark-submit command as mentioned below,which performs the Datasets loading from DB,processing,and in final stage it push the multiple datasets into Oracle DB.

```
./spark-submit --class com.sample.Transformation --conf spark.sql.shuffle.partitions=5001 
    --num-executors=40 --executor-cores=1 --executor-memory=5G 
    --jars /scratch/rmbbuild/spark_ormb/drools-jars/ojdbc6.jar,
        /scratch/rmbbuild/spark_ormb/drools-jars/kie-api-7.7.0.Final.jar,
        /scratch/rmbbuild/spark_ormb/drools-jars/drools-core-7.7.0.Final.jar,
        /scratch/rmbbuild/spark_ormb/drools-jars/drools-compiler-7.7.0.Final.jar,
        /scratch/rmbbuild/spark_ormb/drools-jars/kie-soup-maven-support-7.7.0.Final.jar,
        /scratch/rmbbuild/spark_ormb/drools-jars/kie-internal-7.7.0.Final.jar,
        /scratch/rmbbuild/spark_ormb/drools-jars/xstream-1.4.10.jar,
        /scratch/rmbbuild/spark_ormb/drools-jars/kie-soup-commons-7.7.0.Final.jar,
        /scratch/rmbbuild/spark_ormb/drools-jars/ecj-4.4.2.jar,
        /scratch/rmbbuild/spark_ormb/drools-jars/mvel2-2.4.0.Final.jar,
        /scratch/rmbbuild/spark_ormb/drools-jars/kie-soup-project-datamodel-commons-7.7.0.Final.jar,
        /scratch/rmbbuild/spark_ormb/drools-jars/kie-soup-project-datamodel-api-7.7.0.Final.jar 
    --driver-class-path /scratch/rmbbuild/spark_ormb/drools-jars/ojdbc6.jar 
    --master spark://10.180.181.41:7077 "/scratch/rmbbuild/spark_ormb/POC-jar/Transformation-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar" 
        > /scratch/rmbbuild/spark_ormb/POC-jar/logs/logs12.txt
```

But,it takes some pre-assumed time while writing the dataset into the DB,don't know why it is consuming this long time before starting the write process.
Attaching the screenshot which clearly highlights the problem which i am facing.
Please go through the screenshot before commenting out the solution.
Spark Dashboard Stages Screenshot:

[image]

If we look at the screenshot I have highlighted the timing of around 10mins,which is consumed before every dataset write into the DB.
Even I changed the batchsize to 100000 as such follows:

```
outputDataSetforsummary.write().mode("append").format("jdbc").option("url", connection)
    .option("batchSize", "100000").option("dbtable", CI_TXN_DTL).save();
```

So,if any one can explain out why this pre-write time in consumed everytime,and how to avoid this timings.

I am attaching the code for more description of the program.

```
   public static void main(String[] args) {

        SparkConf conf = new
            //  SparkConf().setAppName("Transformation").setMaster("local");
        SparkConf().setAppName("Transformation").setMaster("spark://xx.xx.xx.xx:7077");
        String connection = "jdbc:oracle:thin:ABC/abc@//xx.x.x.x:1521/ABC";
    
        // Create Spark Context
        SparkContext context = new SparkContext(conf);
        // Create Spark Session
        SparkSession sparkSession = new SparkSession(context);
        Dataset<Row> txnDf  = sparkSession.read().format("jdbc").option("url", connection).option("dbtable", CI_TXN_DETAIL_STG).load();
        //Dataset<Row> txnDf  = sparkSession.read().format("jdbc").option("url", connection).option("dbtable", "CI_TXN_DETAIL_STG").load();
        Dataset<Row> newTxnDf  = txnDf.drop(ACCT_ID);
        
        Dataset<Row> accountDf = sparkSession.read().format("jdbc").option("url", connection).option("dbtable", CI_ACCT_NBR).load();
        //  Dataset<Row> accountDf = sparkSession.read().format("jdbc").option("url", connection).option("dbtable", "CI_ACCT_NBR").load();

        Dataset<Row> joined = newTxnDf.join(accountDf, newTxnDf.col(ACCT_NBR).equalTo(accountDf.col(ACCT_NBR))
                .and(newTxnDf.col(ACCT_NBR_TYPE_CD).equalTo(accountDf.col(ACCT_NBR_TYPE_CD))), "inner");
        Dataset<Row> finalJoined = joined.drop(accountDf.col(ACCT_NBR_TYPE_CD)).drop(accountDf.col(ACCT_NBR))
                .drop(accountDf.col(VERSION)).drop(accountDf.col(PRIM_SW));

        
        initializeProductDerivationCache(sparkSession,connection);
      
        
        ClassTag<List<String>> evidenceForDivision = scala.reflect.ClassTag$.MODULE$.apply(List.class);
        Broadcast<List<String>> broadcastVarForDiv = context.broadcast(divisionList, evidenceForDivision);
        
        ClassTag<List<String>> evidenceForCurrency = scala.reflect.ClassTag$.MODULE$.apply(List.class);
        Broadcast<List<String>> broadcastVarForCurrency = context.broadcast(currencySet, evidenceForCurrency);
        
        ClassTag<List<String>> evidenceForUserID = scala.reflect.ClassTag$.MODULE$.apply(List.class);
        Broadcast<List<String>> broadcastVarForUserID = context.broadcast(userIdList, evidenceForUserID);
        
    
        
        Encoder<RuleParamsBean> encoder = Encoders.bean(RuleParamsBean.class);
        Dataset<RuleParamsBean> ds = new Dataset<RuleParamsBean>(sparkSession, finalJoined.logicalPlan(), encoder);
        Dataset<RuleParamsBean> validateDataset = ds.map(ruleParamsBean -> validateTransaction(ruleParamsBean,broadcastVarForDiv.value(),broadcastVarForCurrency.value(),
                                                            broadcastVarForUserID.value()),encoder);
        
    
        Dataset<RuleParamsBean> filteredDS = validateDataset.filter(validateDataset.col(BO_STATUS_CD).notEqual(TFMAppConstants.TXN_INVALID));
        //For formatting the data to be inserted in table -->   Dataset<Row>finalvalidateDataset = validateDataset.select("ACCT_ID");
        

    
        Encoder<TxnDetailOutput>txndetailencoder = Encoders.bean(TxnDetailOutput.class);
        Dataset<TxnDetailOutput>txndetailDS =validateDataset.map(ruleParamsBean ->outputfortxndetail(ruleParamsBean),txndetailencoder );
        
    
        
        
        KieServices ks = KieServices.Factory.get();
        KieContainer kContainer = ks.getKieClasspathContainer();
        ClassTag<KieBase> classTagTest = scala.reflect.ClassTag$.MODULE$.apply(KieBase.class);
        Broadcast<KieBase> broadcastRules = context.broadcast(kContainer.getKieBase(KIE_BASE), classTagTest);

        Encoder<PritmRuleOutput> outputEncoder = Encoders.bean(PritmRuleOutput.class);
        Dataset<PritmRuleOutput> outputDataSet = filteredDS.flatMap(rulesParamBean -> droolprocesMap(broadcastRules.value(), rulesParamBean), outputEncoder);

        Dataset<Row>piParamDS1 =outputDataSet.select(PRICEITEM_PARM_GRP_VAL);
        Dataset<Row> piParamDS = piParamDS1.withColumnRenamed(PRICEITEM_PARM_GRP_VAL, PARM_STR);

        priceItemParamGrpValueCache.createOrReplaceTempView("temp1");
        Dataset<Row>piParamDSS = piParamDS.where(queryToFiltertheDuplicateParamVal);
        Dataset<Row> priceItemParamsGrpDS = piParamDSS.select(PARM_STR).distinct().withColumn(PRICEITEM_PARM_GRP_ID, functions.monotonically_increasing_id());
        Dataset<Row> finalpriceItemParamsGrpDS = priceItemParamsGrpDS.withColumn(PARM_COUNT, functions.size(functions.split(priceItemParamsGrpDS.col(PARM_STR),TOKENIZER)));
        finalpriceItemParamsGrpDS.persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_ONLY());
        finalpriceItemParamsGrpDS.distinct().write().mode("append").format("jdbc").option("url", connection).option("dbtable", CI_PRICEITEM_PARM_GRP_K).option("batchSize", "1000").save();

            
        
        Dataset<Row> PritmOutput = outputDataSet.join(priceItemParamsGrpDS,outputDataSet.col(PRICEITEM_PARM_GRP_VAL).equalTo(priceItemParamsGrpDS.col(PARM_STR)),"inner");
        Dataset<Row> samplePritmOutput = PritmOutput.drop(outputDataSet.col(PRICEITEM_PARM_GRP_ID))
                .drop(priceItemParamsGrpDS.col(PARM_STR));

        priceItemParamsGrpDS.createOrReplaceTempView(PARM_STR);
        Dataset<Row> priceItemParamsGroupTable =sparkSession.sql(FETCH_QUERY_TO_SPLIT);
        Dataset<Row> finalpriceItemParamsGroupTable = priceItemParamsGroupTable.selectExpr("PRICEITEM_PARM_GRP_ID","split(col, '=')[0] as PRICEITEM_PARM_CD ","split(col, '=')[1] as PRICEITEM_PARM_VAL");
        finalpriceItemParamsGroupTable.persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_ONLY());
        finalpriceItemParamsGroupTable.distinct().write().mode("append").format("jdbc").option("url", connection).option("dbtable", CI_PRICEITEM_PARM_GRP).option("batchSize", "1000").save();
}
```

Comment: Increase no of cores as per you machine configuration, update no of partitions which should be in multiple of cores

Comment: There is no way in order to figure your problem out because of lacking the information:
+ the input size.
+ what kinda computation u are doing.
+ your spark config.

But let's talk about what I can see from the screenshot:
+  It seems like you have 3 actions. So you should consider using persist solution to avoid reloading data from the database in every action. ( on mem or on disk / both)
+ I can see that you are calling persist before really doing some of the heavy computing tasks.

Comment: @tauitdnmd What kind of information do you need can you please elaborate more? I am loading the 10M data from DB into dataset and 1M data into another dataset and then performing various map,flatmap operations.And finally Pushing the dataset after the completion of the above operations into database.If need more info please comment below.

Comment: As I have asked: Are u calling 3 actions? Right? 
According to your input size ( 11 MB in total), it's really small tho. But I can see that shuffle read ~ 1GB. 
So could u please post your code here?

Comment: After calling 'save' at stage 7. Do u re-use the dataframe to do other computings? If yes, should u consider to persit it.
But I do believe that you are setting a too high the number of partitions. 
Let's try with 200 first & increase it a bit more

Comment: Actually my dataset loaded are of 10M and 1M rows data from Database.And also I am using the dataframe further for more operations too.

Comment: With 200 partition(default) it gets failed showing up some Metadata error.

Comment: Also,as shown in the screenshot,the first dataset write is of 50 rows only and the second dataset write is of 200 rows only and the final last save operation writes aroung 10M rows into the database.So,why the pre-assumed time of 10mins is consumed everytime while writing into the database.

Comment: As I said, did you re-use the dataframe after stage 7? Because it loads the whole data from database again in all of 3 save actions.
It's better to show your code please.

Comment: @tauitdnmd I have added the code to view.Please comment the solution which needs to be implemented.

Answer (score 1):

It reloads the whole data and joins data frames again and again in every `write to db` action.

Please add `validateDataset.persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_ONLY())` - (you should consider on mem or on disk or on mem_and_disk on your own depends on your data frame size . Is it fit in mem or not )

For example:

```
 Dataset<RuleParamsBean> validateDataset = ds.map(ruleParamsBean -> validateTransaction(ruleParamsBean,broadcastVarForDiv.value(),broadcastVarForCurrency.value(),broadcastVarForUserID.value()),encoder)
.persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_ONLY());
```

Comment: What should be this parameters to be set to?  ./spark-submit --class com.sample.Transformation --conf spark.sql.shuffle.partitions=5001 
    --num-executors=40 --executor-cores=1 --executor-memory=5G ...As I have two 88 cores Worker machines with 512 GB memory and 1 Master of 4cores and 8 GB memory.Can you please comment on this values